# Possible IE7 Background Bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, background-image, internet-explorer-6

I'm encountering something I've never really come across before in IE7.  I have a wrapper div with a background image applied to it.  This image is supposed to repeat all the way until the end of the wrapper div.  In IE7 there seems to be a scrolling issue where if I use the scroll bar to see parts of the page that aren't initially visible, the background image will 'cut off' and not repeat in the last 100px or so. This only happens if I have to scroll to see more content.  It's like it doesn't fully load the background image for areas that aren't immediately visible.

What's strange is that if I use the mouse wheel to scroll up and down the page, the background image repeats just fine and as it should.  If I use the scroll bar though, it will break randomly (never more than 100px but sometimes just the last 20px, 30, 40 etc).

I've tried the following to trouble shoot so far:
1) Added background color to the div as well.  The background color breaks as well so it's not just a background image repeating issue.
2) Added a min-height of 1% to the wrapper div.
3) Added a position: relative to the div.  I read somewhere that this fixes a weird IE7  background bug.  This didn't help.

Thanks for any help.  I'm unsure if there's some hiccup somewhere else in my code that is causing this (which I'll continue to look into) or if it's some well known IE7 issue.  Again I just find it odd that using the scroll wheel on a mouse let's the background render as it should.  Clicking, holding, and using the scroll bar causes it to break.

EDIT: Here is a link to a screenshot of the horrific problem in action.  http://skitch.com/flight/dspeh/ie7bgerror 
The top one is with the error.  The bottom screen is how it should load.

Another additional thing I noticed: If I minimize the window while it has the broken background and then maximize it again the background image corrects itself.

Comment: Hmm, a screenshot or live link would be helpful here. Also, try to reproduce it on at least one other machine - this could be a graphics driver problem or something (although it seems unlikely).

Comment: This is quite common in IE6 but less so in IE7, do you have a doctype in your html, if not it could be the page is being displayed in quirks mode.

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help.  I added a link to a screenshot of the problem.  Murdoch: The site does have a XHTML strict doctype.

Comment: it's quite hard to know what's happen from a screenshot. 'zoom:1;' usually fix most of the disappearing bugs in IE7, give it a try.

Comment: Please send a link or examples of your code

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the 3 boxes at the bottom are floating div's. Try this:

`#backgroundDiv { overflow:hidden; min-height:100%; height:auto!IMPORTANT; height:100%; }`

IE6/7 sometimes bug with min-height. This piece of code will cause IE6/7 to default to 100%... IE sometimes likes to use the last declaration instead of following the !important call; whereas every other browser will use the !important call when displaying the page.